# unable to resolve NuGet package dependency when using in non-sdk project but works fine with sdk project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I have a NuGet package with the following directory structure.

```
dog.1.0.0.0
      - packages
      - dog.dll
```

This NuGet works and resolves dependencies when use in an SDK Project template project but it does not work with a non-SDK project template project even it gets installed but does not resolve the dependency.

Note: I am using the PackageReferences format for both projects.

Comment: Your question appears to suggest that `dog.dll` is in the root of the package (nupkg/zip). But NuGet would never use this, not even for SDK style projects. This question is missing information I would need to provide an answer. [A working sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help immensely. NuGet generally treats both SDK and non-SDK projects the same, so there's no obvious/common reason why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to install other NuGet packages, will VS resolve their dependencies? I believe the issue will appear for all the NuGet packages.

I think this is because the different structures of non-sdk and new-sdk projects displayed in VS’s Solution Explorer. And for non-sdk project(after using `packagereference` or migrating to `packagereference`), installed NuGet packages will be listed under `References`, and it is not available to see the resolved dependency. But for new-sdk project, VS’s solution Explorer will list it under `Dependencies`, and it is now available to be expanded and you can see the resolved dependencies. By design, should be.